# For loop and replace part string in paths based on dataframe two columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, replace

I try to iterate excel files under a directory with code below:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('./*.xlsx')

for file_path in files:
    print(file_path)
```

Out:

```
./data\S273-2021-12-09.xlsx
./data\S357-2021-12-09.xlsx
./data\S545-2021-12-09.xlsx
./data\S607-2021-12-09.xlsx
```

Now I hope to replace `S273`, `S357`, etc. based dataframe `df` to map `old_name` to `new_name`:

```
  old_name new_name
0     S273        a
1     S357        b
2     S545        c
3     S607        d
4     S281        e
```

To convert dataframe to dictionary if necessary: `name_dict = dict(zip(df.old_name, df.new_name))`

The expected result will like:

```
./data\a-2021-12-09.xlsx
./data\b-2021-12-09.xlsx
./data\c-2021-12-09.xlsx
./data\d-2021-12-09.xlsx
```

How could I achieve that in Python? Sincere thanks at advance.

**EDIT:**

```
for file_path in files:
    for key, value in name_dict.items():
        if key in str(file_path):
            new_path = file_path.replace(key, value)
            print(new_path)
```

The code above works, welcome to share other solutions if it's possible.

Comment: Use `os.rename` with `string.replace`?

Comment: reputation for my case means I ask some useful questions to others @athing

Comment: Not for sure which is more appropriate, finally I will replace `./data\S273-2021-12-09.xlsx` to `.\figures\a-2021-12-09.png`, I'm try to iteratively read excel files, draw plots and save with new names @Vishnudev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split basename first by `os.path.split`, then first part of name of file by `-` and mapping by `dict.get`, if no match is return same value, so second argument is also `first`:

```
import os

name_dict = dict(zip(df.old_name, df.new_name))
print (name_dict)
{'S273': 'a', 'S357': 'b', 'S545': 'c', 'S607': 'd', 'S281': 'e'}

#for test
L = './data\S273-2021-12-09.xlsx ./data\S357-2021-12-09.xlsx ./data\S545-2021-12-09.xlsx ./data\S607-2021-12-09.xlsx' 
files = L.split()
```

---

```
for file_path in files:
    head, tail = os.path.split(file_path)
    first, last = tail.split('-', 1)
    out = os.path.join(head, f'{name_dict.get(first, first)}-{last}')
    print(out)
    
./data\a-2021-12-09.xlsx
./data\b-2021-12-09.xlsx
./data\c-2021-12-09.xlsx
./data\d-2021-12-09.xlsx
```

Comment: Many thanks, however `f'{name_dict.get(first, first)}-{last}'` seem not easy to understand for me even after I read dict.get() from https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get.

Comment: yop, it means for dictionary `d` try match first value `first` and if no match return sam evalue - it means `name_dict.get(first, first)`, all another is joined in `f-strings`